# How to get RAW Html code from my module?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I looked around for a few hours but wasn't able to find any available hooks to get pure raw html code. If you right-click on any webpage and do "get source", it will give you the raw html output.

However, there doesn't seem to be a function or hook available that I can find in Drupal that does this.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Thank you.

Comment: Why not just curl the URL? Then you’ll get the same source as in the browser. Failing that you’ll have to set a bunch of environment variables and basically do the same process as you see in index.php. The entire request, from index.php to output, is needed to produce the HTML, so doing it inside of another Drupal request might not be the best idea.

Comment: Do you want the raw html of a block, view, node content, whole page? More details are needed to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you mean by 'from my module' but if you're asking how to get the HTML code of any Url into a variable in your module, you can use the [drupal_http_request](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7.x) function. Below example comes from https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7.x

```
$data = 'name=value&name1=value1';

$options = array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'data' => $data,
                'timeout' => 15,
                'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
        );

$result = drupal_http_request('http://somewhere.com', $options);
```

You can also use curl via the [cURL HTTP Request (chr)](https://www.drupal.org/project/chr) module.